# Encountering difficulties while writing tests with .connect(notDeployer)

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, chai

I am currently working on my tests on hardhat, and I am currently stuck while trying to perform a transaction with another account than the deployer. Here is the test:

```
...
 describe("gift", async function () {
...
    it("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
                    

                  const connectacc2 = await LPR.connect(
                      "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8"
                  )
                  await expect(
                      connectacc2.gift("0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC")
                  ).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
              })
```

Somehow I feel that the issue lies with this .connect(), because I've been successfully passing other tests.

```
doesn't allow others to gift:
     Error: VoidSigner cannot sign transactions (operation="signTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at /home/giorgio/LPR/LPR-Back/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/src.ts/index.ts:355:20
```

I've tried also to do it with using

```
 ;[addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners()
```

instead of directly writing the addresses but I get similar errors

```
       gift
         doesn't allow others to gift:
     Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8>", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:285:21)
      at /home/giorgio/LPR/LPR-Back/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:123:16
      at step (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So I am a bit confused with what is happening here, has anyone encountered similar errors in this situation ?

---

edit

Here is the full concerned part of the code giving me issues

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers, deployments, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChains,

} = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("LPR", function () {
          let LPR, deployer, addr1, addr2, addr3
          beforeEach(async function () {
              ;[addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners()
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              await deployments.fixture(["all", "LPR"])
              LPR = await ethers.getContract("LPR", deployer)
          })
             describe("gift", async function () {
                  it("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
                  
                   expect(await LPR.connect(addr1.address).gift(addr2.address)).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
              })
        })
})
```

and this is the gift function

```
    function gift(address _account) external onlyOwner {
        if (totalSupply() + 1 > MAX_SUPPLY) {
            revert LPR__MintGiftExceeded();
        }

        _safeMint(_account, (s_nftIdCounter).current());
        (s_nftIdCounter).increment();
    }
```

I also tried the other option of doing

```
it.only("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
                  ;[addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners()
                  expect(await LPR.connect(addr1).gift(addr2)).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
```

but I get this error

```
Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8>", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

---

After having tried different addresses for both the .connect() an gift() I've noticed that the invalid address or ENS name always reports the address that I put in the gift() function...

---

PROBLEM SOLVED

Okay so after playing around with the gift() arguments, I finally **passed my test**

```
    it("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
        await expect(
            LPR.connect(addr2).gift("0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906")
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
    })
// or

 it("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
        await expect(
            LPR.connect(addr2).gift(addr1.address)
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
    })
```

I don't know why but if I put addr1, or addr2 in the gift arguments, it won't work, I have to put the address this way, even though it works, I am actually not sure why or why it wasn't working... Anyways thanks for the all the precious help !

Comment: What is this ```getContract``` ? Does this exist ? I couldn't find this in ethersjs docs

Comment: Actually I am using hardhat-deploy to deploy my contract,  `await deployments.fixture(["all", "LPR"])` this line will keep track of all the previous deployments. And hardhat-deploy comes with a function, `getContract`, which will wrap ethersjs, and get for us the most recent deployment of the contract name that we give it. hence the deployments import in `const { ethers, deployments, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to a signer, not an address.

```
accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
await LPR.connect(accounts[1]).gift(someAddress)
```

Comment: doesn't `accounts = await ethers.getSigners()` pretty much do the same as  `;[addr1, addr2,a ddr3] = await ethers.getSigners()` ?

Comment: @GiorgioDG That is true, but the point here is the second line, when you call connect, you should pass one of the objects you get from getSigners(), but not a string (not accounts[1].address).

Answer (score 1):

well do this way here we are connecting `addr1` and gifting to `addr2`

```
const connectacc2 = await LPR.connect(addr1.address).gift(addr2.address);
```

Comment: I tried this one, sadly also won't get me pass my test .. I am getting the Void signer error

Comment: send me the full code i get to know it first

Comment: I've edited my initial post, you can now take a peak if you would like to

Comment: actually This will not work because `.connect()` expects a `signer` and not an `address`

Answer (score 1):

According to ethersjs docs:

> A Signer in ethers is an abstraction of an Ethereum Account, which can
> be used to sign messages and transactions and send signed transactions
> to the Ethereum Network to execute state changing operations.

Why don't you do something like this -

```
describe("LPR", function () {
  let LPR,lpr;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    [deployer, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();
    LPR = await ethers.getContractFactory("LPR");
    lpr = await LPR.deploy();
    await lpr.deployed();
  });

    ...
 /**  LPR.connect(addr1.address) - this is the problem in code. 
Shouldn't use address since it accepts an account object
**/

    it("doesn't allow others to gift", async function () {
          expect(await LPR.connect(addr1).gift(deployer.address)).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
     })

   ...

  }
```

Comment: thanks again for your help fren, 
It looks similar to what I already tried... I still get the 
`Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266>", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)`

Comment: do you have this code hosted somewhere, I might try it in my local

Comment: hey fren, I finally made it work, but as I said in my answer I don't really know why it wasn't working. But at least it works :)

Comment: Fren, can you put the updated code (in a new section at the end) in the question. So others can also know.

Comment: is it this line, where you removed (.address)  ```expect(await LPR.connect(addr1).gift(deployer)).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")``` ?

Comment: Yes I removed the (.address) but If I wanted
 `expect(await LPR.connect(addr1).gift(deployer)).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")`
 this to work I should do
 `expect(awaitLPR.connect(addr1).gift(deployer.address).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner") `
(added `.address` to `deployer`)

Answer (score 0):

To do a transaction from other than the default account you can do like this:

`accounts = await ethers.getSigners()` 
`await LPR.connect(accounts[1]).gift(someAddress)`

Moreover, we can also destructure the accounts array and use it like this:

`[owner, otherAccount] = await ethers.getSigners()`
`await LPR.connect(otherAccount).gift(someAddress)`

If you also want to deploy a contract from other than the default account you can do it like this:

`const Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Factory", otherAccount);` 
`const contract = await Factory.deploy()`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really want to deploy the contract from another account. 
I've already tried something which is similar, and somehow I get invalid Address or ENS name..